# How to create two buttons in the Dash package of Python which can modify both a cardbody, each in its own way?

Tags: python, button, input, callback, plotly-dash

I have a problem with the app.callback function, I want that by pressing the top_masse button, I change the interior of a cardBody and when I press the top_masse button, I also change the cardBody, from another way. The problem is when in my code, the change is made on the first button but not the second, and I do not understand where the problem is yet it takes into account the number of clicks.
Here is the code in simplified version :

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table as dt

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

tarif_jumb = dbc.Jumbotron([
        html.H2("Tarification", className="display-3"),
        html.Hr(className="my-2",),
        html.P(),
        dbc.Button("Tarif en masse", color="primary", className="mr-3", id="top_masse"),
        dbc.Button("Tarif parc", color="danger", className="mr-3", id="top_parc")
        ,])
    
card_top_tarif = dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody([
                    tarif_jumb
                    ,])
            , className="mt-3"
            ,)

tab_top_tarif = dbc.Tab(card_top_tarif, label="Choix tarifaire", tab_id="top_tarif",id="top_tarif")

tabs = dbc.Card(dbc.CardBody([
        dbc.Tabs([
            tab_top_tarif
            ,]
            , id="tabs"
            , active_tab="top_tarif"
            ,)
        ,],
        id="card_body"
        ,))
        
app.layout  = dbc.Container([
        tabs
        ,],)

@app.callback(Output(component_id="card_body", component_property="children"),
               [Input(component_id="top_masse", component_property="n_clicks"),
              Input(component_id="top_parc", component_property="n_clicks")
              ,])

def tarif_masse(n_clicks1,n_clicks2):

    if n_clicks1>=1:
        return dbc.Alert('The button has been clicked {} times'.format(n_clicks2), color="primary")
    elif n_clicks2>=1:
        return dbc.Alert('The button has been clicked {} times'.format(n_clicks1), color="primary")

    
@app.callback(Output(component_id="alert", component_property="children"), 
              [Input(component_id="importation", component_property="n_clicks")
              ,])

def tarif_masse(n_clicks):

    if n_clicks>=1:
        return 'The button has been clicked {} times'.format(n_clicks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False,port=8080,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just had to define 'else' and it works, I can't explain it but it works.

````
@app.callback(Output(component_id="card_body", component_property="children"),

               [Input(component_id="top_masse", component_property="n_clicks"),

              Input(component_id="top_parc", component_property="n_clicks")

              ,])

def tarif_masse(n_clicks1,n_clicks2):

    if n_clicks1 is not None:

        return dbc.Alert('The button has been clicked {} times'.format(n_clicks1), 

color="primary")

    elif n_clicks2 is not None:

        return dbc.Alert('The button hed {} times'.format(n_clicks2), color="primary")

    else:

        return dbc.Tabs([tab_top_tarif,], id="tabs", active_tab="top_tarif")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run_server(debug=False,port=8050,host='0.0.0.0')```
````